# Google Maps Error - Invalid latitude / longitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="googleMap" style="height:500px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.6656, -83.5753),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
          ,mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapProp,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The map displays fine but I can't add the marker. I get the following error:

```
setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

I don't see how the latitude and longitude could be invalid because the resulting generated map shows the correct location. But no marker.

Comment: mapProp is not a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker's `position` property should be of the type `LatLng`:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="googleMap" style="height:500px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function initialize() {

        var cord = new google.maps.LatLng(41.6656, -83.5753);

        var mapProp = {
            center: cord,
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
          ,mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: cord,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5am3V/

Comment: @RandyMinder Np! Use the LatLng "class" when it comes to coordinates.